# How to put constraints on HTML form inputs?

Tags: html, forms

[image]

I have a form that looks like this.
What I want to do is, I want to make sure that `Minimum Age` < `Maximum Age`
and `Minimum Skill Level` < `Maximum Skill Level`

What is a way to put constraints on the inputs?

**HTML**

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% set active_page = "events" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbo">
        <h2>EVENTS PAGE</h2>
        <br/>
        <p>Click <a href="/welcome">here</a> to go to the welcome page</p>
    </div>

    <form action = "/events_success" method=post>
      Event Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="eventname" required="">
      <br>
      Sports:<br>
      <select name="sports">
       {% for item in sports_data %}
         <option value="{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[0] }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>

      <br>

     Location:<br>
      <select name="location">
       {% for item in loc_data %}
         <option value="{{ item[0] }}">{{ item[0] }}</option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>

      <br>
      Time:<br>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="time" required>

      <br>
      Number of Players:<br>
      <input type="text" name="numplayers" required>
      <br>
      Minimum Age:<br>
      <input type="text" name="minage" required>
      <br>
      Maximum Age:<br>
      <input type="text" name="maxage" required>
      <br>
      Minimum Skill Level:<br>
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "1" required> 1
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "2"> 2
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "3"> 3
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "4"> 4
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "5"> 5
      <br>
      Maximum Skill Level:<br>
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "1" required> 1
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "2"> 2
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "3"> 3
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "4"> 4
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "5"> 5
      <br>
      <br>
      Creator: {{ session['username'] }}<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try some javaScript to prevent the form submission if those fields fails to fulfill that condition. Please check my demo.

**Note: It's just a demo. That's why didn't put any authentication.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
    
    function validateAge(minAge, maxAge) {
        let min = parseInt(minAge, 10);
        let max = parseInt(maxAge, 10);
        return min >= max ?  false :  true;
    }
    function validateSkill(minSkill, maxSkill) {
        let min = parseInt(minSkill, 10);
        let max = parseInt(maxSkill, 10);
        return min >= max ?  false :  true;
    }
    
    submit.onclick = function() {
        let minAge = document.querySelector("#minage").value;
        let maxAge = document.querySelector("#maxage").value;
        let radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        let minSkill = radios[0].value;
        let maxSkill = radios[1].value;
    
        if(validateAge(minAge, maxAge) && validateSkill(minSkill, maxSkill))
            return  true;
        else {
            alert("Invalid data");
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
    <form id="myForm" action = "/events_success" method=post >

      Minimum Age:<br>
      <input type="text" name="minage" id="minage" required>
      <br>
      Maximum Age:<br>
      <input type="text" name="maxage" id="maxage"  required>
      <br>
       Minimum Skill Level:<br>
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "1" required> 1
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "2"> 2
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "3"> 3
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "4"> 4
      <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "5"> 5
      <br>
      Maximum Skill Level:<br>
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "1" required> 1
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "2"> 2
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "3"> 3
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "4"> 4
      <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "5"> 5
      <br>
      <br>
  
      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: You should never rely on a given user having javascript enabled. You should also keep in mind that a user might use a scripting language such as GreaseMonkey. What you could do is to use ajax to submit the entered value and have your server-side validate the submitted data, then display an error to the user if it's invalid data that they've submitted

Comment: Thanks i get your point. But i've just shown a way how this can be handled to put some constraints in input fields. @SpacePhoenix

Answer (score 0):

You can use some common PHP validation techniques. These are more beneficial as less risky to injection and other exploits.

PHP:

```
  if (empty($_POST["code"])) {
    $errcode = "Verify that you're human";
  } else {
    $code = test_input($_POST["code"]);
    if (!$_POST['code'] < $string) {
      $errcode = "Make code greater than string";
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<p><label for="code">Scrambled code:  </label><input type="text" name="code" id="code" /><span class="error">  * <?php echo $errcode;?></span></p>
```